# Unable to modifiy the Folder custom column inside my CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code inside my CSOM:-

```
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.ExecuteQuery();

currentFilingSystemItem["DealStage"] =  "7178cede-c689-4b47-853a-88bb8b95e230";;
currentFilingSystemItem.Update();
folder.ListItemAllFields["DealStage"] = "7178cede-c689-4b47-853a-88bb8b95e230";
folder.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

the above code will update the list item `currentFilingSystemItem` DealStage value but will not update the folder DealStage value. the DealStage is a managed metadata coumn which alllow single selection. Any advice?

Regards

Comment: Does `DealStage` allow multiple term selections, or is it just Single Value?

Comment: @willman single value only

Comment: okay, I have updated a few things (including a couple of types) in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`folder.ListItemAllFields` return `ListItem` object which you need to update not the `folder` object. Try following way to update.

```
ListItem item = folder.ListItemAllFields;
item["DealStage"] = "7178cede-c689-4b47-853a-88bb8b95e230";
item.Update();
```

Comment: this will not raise any error but will not update the DealStage

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is that you are calling `Update()` on the `folder`, when you need to call it on the `ListItemAllFields` property:

```
folder.ListItemAllFields["DealStage"] = "7178cede-c689-4b47-853a-88bb8b95e230";
folder.ListItemAllFields.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But, secondarily, you should use [`TaxonomyFieldValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvalue?view=sharepoint-server) (for single-value managed metadata columns) and [`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvaluecollection?view=sharepoint-server) (for multi-value managed metadata columns).  If your `currentFilingSystemItem`, then you may have gotten lucky, in most cases, setting a taxonomy field to a raw guid will not update the value correctly.  Also note the use of the `SetFieldValueByValue` method on the actual Field object, rather than simply setting the field equal to a value.  Taxonomy fields are considerably more difficult to code updates for than scalar value fields are.  Your code should look more like this:

```
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.Load(folder);
var folderListItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
context.Load(folderListItem);
var dealStageField = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("DealStage");
context.Load(dealStageField);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var dealStageTaxField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
var dealStageTermValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
//dealStageTermValue.Label = "Display Text from the Term"; // Note that if you do not set this value, or you set it to a value that doesn't match what is in the termstore, the value may display incorrectly in list views for several minutes before SharePoint synchronizes from the termstore.
dealStageTermValue.TermGuid = new Guid("7178cede-c689-4b47-853a-88bb8b95e230");
dealStageTermValue.WssId = -1;

dealStageTaxField.SetFieldValueByValue(currentFilingSystemItem, dealStageTermValue);
currentFilingSystemItem.Update();

dealStageTaxField.SetFieldValueByValue(folderListItem, dealStageTermValue);
folderListItem.Update();

context.ExecuteQuery();
```